# Creating a countdown timer from the time inputted on a textbox - C#

Tags: c#

I want to create a countdown from a time that a user inputs on a form.

Code:

```
  int Hours = 0;
  // converts the text to an integer
  Int32.TryParse(txtHours.Text, out Hours);
  Hours = (Hours * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  var StartTime = DateTime.Now;
  var Timer= new Timer() { Interval = Hours };
  Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick; 
  if(Hours == 0)
  {
  MessageBox.Show("message");
  }
```

Not sure why its not working!

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the Timer_Tick event code? And what exactly isn't working? *Not working* doesn't tell us much, are you getting an error? Is the counter not counting down? Please add more detail.

Comment: I don't understand timers, just reading up about them now. I just want to say, after a certain amount of hours, display a message box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that the entire code snippet for the timer?  If so it never looks like you started the timer.. You need

`Timer.Enabled = true` or `Timer.Start()`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Timer(v=vs.110).aspx

```
int ticks = 0;
int hours;
Timer timer;
public void SetupTimer() {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
    Int32.TryParse(txtHours.Text, out hours);
    timer.Interval = 60 * 60 * 1000; // raise tick event every hour
    timer.Start();
}

private static void Timer_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs args) {
    if (ticks >= hours)
        MessageBox.show("Timer Done");
    else
        ticks++;
}
```

Edit: This is the link you should be checking out.

Comment: So if I timer.start(), will it run for the selected time? I need an if statement saying, when the timer has finished it needs to show a messagebox.

Comment: It sounds like you are using System.Windows.Forms.Timer. As far as I remember you need to have a variable somewhere in your code to keep track of the ticks, as the timer does not handle that. All the timer does is raise the Tick event every given interval, it does not keep track of the number of time it "ticked".

Comment: Please explain what you wish to accomplish a bit further. Does the user simply input the number of hours they want the timer to run for?

Comment: Yes! I literally want to say, after for example 8 hours, display a message box.